# Element should have been "select" but was "div" error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

HTML code of the desired element:

```
<select class="fcr-height-parent oj-select-select oj-component-initnode oj-select-options-generated" data-bind="attr:{id: idTag, name: idTag}, id="40026501instrChqClgType" name="40026501instrChqClgType" aria-required="true" style="border-color: rgb(4, 95, 171);"><option class="oj-listbox-result oj-listbox-result-selectable oj-listbox-results-depth-0" role="option" id="oj-listbox-result-label-14" value=""></option></select></div>
```

Selenium code:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[contains(@id,'instrChqClgType')])))
```

Getting the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div"

What could be the reason?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092193/element-should-have-been-select-but-was-div-getting-an-error-in-selenium

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that *your XPath expression matches a `div` element while `Select` class constructor expects a `select` element*.

This can be explained by the use of a wildcard `*` in your XPath expression. Or, to put it differently, your selector matches another element, which happens to be a `div` element, which has an `id` containing `instrChqClgType`.

A quick and easy way to fix it, would be to explicitly search for `select` instead of `*`:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id,'instrChqClgType')]")))
//                                        ^HERE^
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium `Select` class is works for HTML `<select>` tag. refer [this](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

In your code, you have written the xpath which is locating any element which contains `id = instrChqClgType`. That's the reason it locating the div tag with the above mentioned id instead of `<select>` tag and throwing the error.

**Solution:** refer @alecxe solution using xpath :

```
//select[contains(@id,'instrChqClgType')]
```

OR try some alternate locator like CSS selector

```
select[name$='instrChqClgType']
```

This will locate the select tag having said text in the ending of `name` attribute. and below for `id` attribute

```
select[id$='instrChqClgType']
```